# Restrict drive files to select android

Tags: android, file, select, android-sdcard, drive

I want to choose different format files for uploading to local server. But i dont wanna choose drive files. This is my code,

```
private void showFileChooser(int position) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

        try {
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"), position);
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

In this code i am selecting all format files which also opens drive options i want to remove it.